# Angular5: Deploying Angular application to multiple clients locally

Tags: node.js, angular

How can I run AngularJS for multiple clients locally with LAN wires?

Give instruction how to do it

Comment: Is your question about angularjs or angular5?

Comment: my question is on angular5

Comment: Angularjs stands for angular == 1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about accessing to your local build from other machines in your network for developing purposes.

Run command:

`ng serve --host=0.0.0.0`

Where 0.0.0.0 is IP of your machine.

In case you get "Invalid Host Header" error, use `ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`